# How to pass an argument to roslaunch file from shell script?

Tags: ros, rosbag, shell, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a shell script that takes some input from the user in the form of arguments and executes a launch file with some nodes. One of these nodes is a `rosbag record`. Currently, I have hardcoded the output directory for the recorded bag, but I'd like to parametrize this and let the user decide where to store the folder from the shell script.

I start the node like this at the moment:

`<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record" output="screen" args="-o /home/output/output_name -e /myTopic"/>`

I cannot figure out how to to pass this `args` from a shell script. Any ideas? it should be possible...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211067/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-roslaunch-file-from-shell-script?/) by [lapadets](https://answers.ros.org/users/22718/lapadets/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `arg` element in launch syntax. http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg

An example can look like:

rosbag_record.launch:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="hoge" default="fuga" />
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record" output="screen" args="-o $(arg hoge) -e /myTopic"/>
</launch>
```

top_level.launch:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="hoge" default="fuga" />
  <include file="rosbag_record.launch">
    <arg name="hoge" value="$(arg hoge)" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

And you can run

```
roslaunch top_level.launch hoge:=my_value
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lapadets](https://answers.ros.org/users/22718/lapadets/) on 2015-06-11**:
But do you need to have the `<arg>` in both launch files? So `myScript.sh` runs`top_level.launch`, which contains `rosbag_record.launch`. Or the  tag is in the top_level, while the  tag is in the other launcher? or?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-06-11**:
@lapadets sorry, my sample was completely wrong. Now it's corrected with the file structures you provided in addition.

**Comment by [lapadets](https://answers.ros.org/users/22718/lapadets/) on 2015-06-11**:
Thanks! that's way more clear now!